# ImageView placement not correct

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to load an image from the internet and put it in an `ImageView`, but I want to use the screens width as the width for the image and keep the aspect ratio. I've tried all the solutions here on stackoverflow, but it does not help. I think because i'm loading the image afterwards from the internet and put it into the `ImageView`.

Here is the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".ViewPhoto"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/title" 
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        />

    <ImageView 
        ??

        />

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"               
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: r u not getting the proper aspect ratio is it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
    />
```

try in this way

Comment: now the width is not as the screen width, when i'm using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, the height is not correct anymore. Pretty weird

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` inside your `ImageView`.

Comment: now the width is not as the screen width, when i'm using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, the height is not correct anymore.

Comment: what is the dpi of your device and what is resolution of your image.

Comment: my dpi is 320, resolution 256 × 192

Comment: put your image dwrable-xhdpi folder and tell me what happening.

Comment: now the aspect ratio remains the same, but i can't scroll down to the bottom part of the photo. The width is OK.

Comment: when adding it from drawable: http://i37.tinypic.com/28tv1w6.jpg when downloading from internet: http://i36.tinypic.com/ou8vq0.png

Comment: post it in stack overflow i cant access it from that link .

Comment: Not enough rep. Maybe those links? drawable: http://snag.gy/ACvw6.jpg internet: http://snag.gy/vxMz7.jpg